# Rails not serving my robots.txt and sitemap.xml.gz on Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

While these files are being served in development fine, and also in production on my local machine, these are not served on live production. I get a 404 not found error. Everything else is working fine. These files are present in the public directory of the app (-approot-/public)

I am using `nginx` and `unicorn` over the live server. My `nginx/sites-available/default` file:

```
upstream example.com {
 server unix:/tmp/example.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  root /home/myuser/apps/example/current/public;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  rewrite_log on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://example.com;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;

    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
   }

  location ~ ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets|assets|system)/  {
    root /home/myuser/apps/example/current/public;
    expires max;
    break;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write one more location rule like

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  root /home/myuser/apps/example/current/public;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 rewrite_log on;

location / {
proxy_pass  http://example.com;
proxy_redirect     off;
proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

client_max_body_size       10m;
client_body_buffer_size    128k;

proxy_connect_timeout      90;
proxy_send_timeout         90;
proxy_read_timeout         90;

proxy_buffer_size          4k;
proxy_buffers              4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}

location ~ ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets|assets|system)/  {
root /home/myuser/apps/example/current/public;
expires max;
break;
}
location ~ ^/(robots.txt|sitemap.xml.gz)/  {
root /home/myuser/apps/example/current/public;

}

}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, I had to do `location ~ ^/.+\.(gz|txt)$ {}`.

Answer (score 1):

Append this to `etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
location ~ ^/(robots.txt|sitemap.xml.gz) {
  root /home/<user>/apps/<appname>/current/public;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, I had to do `location ~ ^/.+\.(gz|txt)$ {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Append this to etc/nginx/sites-available/{your-app-config-file}:

```
location ~ .*(robots.txt|sitemap.xml.gz) {
  # if you already set root above, then the following line is not needed.
  root /path_to_app/public;
}
```